# How can I fix the xception model

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I would like to train a model which can seperate different cat's can,but it's seems to be false,and I don't know why the model can't predict correctly.
The dataset we made by ourself,and we took photos from different angles.
I'm not sure which part is wrong.
Would you please help to see how can I get the model?
Here is my code:

```
import keras.backend
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import Xception

train_path = './train'
test_path = './test'

batch_size = 16
image_size = (224,224)
epoch = 30
FREEZE_LAYERS = 2

model = Xception(include_top=False,
          weights='imagenet',
          input_shape=(224,224, 3))

x = model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(26, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)


model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
       loss='categorical_crossentropy',
       metrics=['accuracy'])

estop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, mode='min', verbose=1)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('Xception_checkpoint.h5', verbose=1,
                monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True,
                mode='max')
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5,
                patience=5, mode='min', verbose=1,
                min_lr=1e-4)


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1.0/255,
                    rotation_range=30,
                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                    shear_range=0.2,
                    zoom_range=0.2,
                    channel_shift_range=10,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    fill_mode='nearest')

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1.0/255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,
                            target_size=image_size,
                            class_mode='categorical',
                            shuffle=True,
                            batch_size=batch_size)

valid_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                            target_size=image_size,
                            class_mode='categorical',
                            shuffle=False,
                            batch_size=batch_size)

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                epochs=epoch, verbose=1,
                steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples//batch_size,
                validation_data=valid_generator,
                validation_steps=valid_generator.samples//batch_size,
                callbacks=[checkpoint, estop, reduce_lr])
                #class_weight=class_weights)

model.save('./Xception_retrained_v2.h5')
print('saved Xception_retrained_v2.h5')
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the model running? Is the loss decreasing or not at all? From a quick look, the part where you keep overwriting `x` with a recursive layer call looks wrong, but I'm not entirely sure.  If that is the problem, you could instead try `tf.keras.sequential`.

Comment: It can run actually,but when I give an unknown photo to the model,it reply the wrong answer.

Comment: Does the model appear to be learning at all, i.e. does the loss go down during training?

Comment: Yes,the val_loss goes down and val_accu up normally,I don't know where's the problem at...><